# Re-produce Stacked Bar Graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I have below table and needed to reproduce the chart generated in Excel.

```
zz <- "Group_1    57.05%    42.95%
Group_2 33.67%  66.33%
Group_3 11.63%  88.37%
Group_4 50.97%  49.03%
Group_5 0.00%   0.00%
"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = FALSE)
Data
       V1     V2     V3
1 Group_1 57.05% 42.95%
2 Group_2 33.67% 66.33%
3 Group_3 11.63% 88.37%
4 Group_4 50.97% 49.03%
5 Group_5  0.00%  0.00%
colnames(Data) <- c("Division","InCorrect_Routing","Correct_Routing")
```

Is it possible to reproduce the below stacked graph in R

[image]

```
zz1 <- "Group_1    0    4   100%
Group_2 29  110 79%
Group_3 0   1   100%
Group_4 17  36  68%
Group_5 6   22  79%
Group_6 14  27  66%
Group_7 252 3417    93%
Group_8 0   3   100%
Group_9 227 523 70%
"

Data1 <- read.table(text=zz1, header = FALSE)
colnames(Data1) <- c("Division","Wrongly_Routed","Correctly_Routed","Routing_Accuracy")
Data1
  Division Wrongly_Routed Correctly_Routed Routing_Accuracy
1  Group_1              0                4             100%
2  Group_2             29              110              79%
3  Group_3              0                1             100%
4  Group_4             17               36              68%
5  Group_5              6               22              79%
6  Group_6             14               27              66%
7  Group_7            252             3417              93%
8  Group_8              0                3             100%
9  Group_9            227              523              70%
```

[image]

Comment: "Is it possible to reproduce the below stacked graph in R"? Yes. However, it appears that you don't have a specific programming question, but are asking for code to be written from scratch. StackOverflow is not the place to ask for such services.

Comment: I am new to `ggplot2` and trying to figure how to best reproduce the graph . I have seen the link suggested and using them to replicate